# Can I integrate Unity 5 with the 0.6.0 runtime for Oculus DK2?

Tags: unity, oculus

I am a new user and I am trying to get the Oculus running on an old PC. I had a few issues with the latest SDK so I am currently using the 0.6.0.1-beta version. I would like to integrate Oculus with Unity. My question is whether I can use Unity 5 with the SDK 0.6.0.1-beta and which kind of integration should I use - or if I should download a previous release of Unity. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use pre-0.7 SDKs with Unity versions before 5.2.1.

Under 'Changes' [here](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.2.1) you can see that you must use the 0.7+ SDK starting with 5.2.1.

Comment: What do you think should be the latest version of Unity I can use with the 0.6.0 runtime?

Comment: I haven't tried with 0.6.0 myself, but 5.2.0p1 should be fine, which I believe is the currently available download of 5.2 on https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive